# Subclassing MKAnnotation cause Set collection doesn’t work

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, set, mapkit

I've just found that `Set` of type `MKAnnotation` doesn't work as expected.

```
class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    let id: String

    init(_ id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return id.hash
    }

    static func ==(lhs: MyAnnotation, rhs: MyAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

let m1 = MyAnnotation("1")
let m2 = MyAnnotation("2")
let n1 = MyAnnotation("1")
let n2 = MyAnnotation("2")

m1.hashValue //918
n1.hashValue //918

m2.hashValue //921
n2.hashValue //921

if m1 == n1 && m2 == n2 {
    print(true)
}
// prints true

let s1 = Set(arrayLiteral: m1, m2)
let s2 = Set(arrayLiteral: n1, n2)

let i = s1.intersection(s2)
// empty
```

Intersection of m's and n's is empty even so hashes are the same. Please, compare with example below:

```
class MyAnnotation: Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: String

    init(_ id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hash
   }

    static func ==(lhs: MyAnnotation, rhs: MyAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

let m1 = MyAnnotation("1")
let m2 = MyAnnotation("2")
let n1 = MyAnnotation("1")
let n2 = MyAnnotation("2")

m1.hashValue //918
n1.hashValue //918

m2.hashValue //921
n2.hashValue //921

if m1 == n1 && m2 == n2 {
    print(true)
}
// prints true

let s1 = Set(arrayLiteral: m1, m2)
let s2 = Set(arrayLiteral: n1, n2)

let i = s1.intersection(s2)
// {{id "1"}, {id "2"}}
```

Intersection of m's and n's is as expected.

Isn't it weird? Maybe there is something in the middle I don't know nor understand.

Xcode 10.1

Comment: you miss Hashable in first part

Comment: @Sh_Khan `MKAnnotation` conforms to `Equatable` and `Hashable` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override `isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool`.

Because `MKAnnotation` is derived from `NSObject` we need to override NS's method. If we dig into implementation (`^` + `⌘`) we would find:

> Subclasses of `NSObject` can customize Equatable conformance by overriding `isEqual(_:)`. If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value, so if you override `isEqual(_:)`, make sure you also override the `hash` property.

Answer (score 0):

In first code, you haven't use Equatable protocol but in second code you have used Equatable protocol so it is working.

Equatable protocol is used for comparison. You can refer below link for more information:

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-equatable-and-comparable/

Comment: But `MKPointAnnotation` conforms to Equatable and Hashable.